# Validation rule only when New creation

Tags: validation-rule

I hope someone can help me with this issue I'm having. I have a validation rule that given a date value should only apply. So any historical data should not be affected. The rule is

```
AND(
    DateValue(CreatedDate) >= (2020, 04, 18), 
    (
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(Lead_Source_Sub_Category__c, "Outbound")
        )
    )
    && ISBLANK(URN__c)
```

This works if I add the URN field with values with new created ones but any historical agreements where URN will be blank should still be able to be updated or edited etc... without getting an error.

It throws an error because the URN is blank on historical ones, but will work on the new ones as this is a new function introduced.

How can I make it work that the rule only applies when it's a new agreement created? I used the created date because from that date onwards it should only apply when those conditions are met and anything historical shouldn't get errors.

Comment: Try using the ISNEW() in your validation rule to make sure it works only on creation and not on update.

Comment: The formula you've provided should not compile as written. Mixing logical operators (`AND()` + `OR()` with `||` + `&&`) should be avoided because it makes it harder to understand your formula (making it harder to debug/maintain). Pick one style, and stick with it. If you pick `AND()` and `OR()`, be aware that those functions are only really useful if they each have at least 2 arguments.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the feedback. I realised the ISNEW and that did the trick.